# Calculate $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(2x)}{x(y^{2} - 1)} $

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

According to Wolframalpha

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{sin(2x)}{x(y^{2} - 1)} = -2$$

I have no idea on how to begin, the book I have only covers squeeze theorem to compute limits that exist, but I have tried to use it with $sin(2x)$ and I could not find a solution. Can someone please show me how to get to this answer?

Comment: What is the limit of $\frac {\sin (2x)} {2x}$ as $x \to 0$?

Comment: And what is the limit of $\frac{1}{y^2-1}$ as $y\to 0$?

Comment: $\sin(2x)\sim 2x$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Comment: And another hint $\frac{\sin 2x}{x(y^{2}-1)}=\frac{\sin 2x}{x}\times \frac{1}{y^{2}-1}$ I think that is all, knowing some basic theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my attempt at this question.

We have;
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x(y^2 - 1)}
&=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{(y^2 - 1)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{(y^2 - 1)}\right)\\
&=\left(\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\right)\left(\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{1}{(y^2 - 1)}\right).
\end{align*}

Notice that in the final value, the first term doesn't depend on $y$ at all, and the second term doesn't depend on $x$ at all. So we don't need $(x,y)\rightarrow 0$ on both the terms, and can instead have $x\rightarrow 0$ on the first term, and $y\rightarrow 0$ on the second term;
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x(y^2 - 1)}
&=\left(\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\right)\left(\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{1}{(y^2 - 1)}\right)\\
&=\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\right)\left(\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{(y^2 - 1)}\right).
\end{align*}

The first limit can be calculated using the L'Hôpital's rule because both the numerator and the denominator are approaching $0$. We have;
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(\sin(2x)\right)'}{(x)'}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\left(\cos(2x)\right)'}{1}\\
&=2\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\cos(2x)\right)\\
&=2\cdot 1\\
&=2.
\end{align*}

On the second part, we have to calculate the limit of a function which is continuous at the value $y=0$;
$$\text{This is the function }\rightarrow \frac{1}{y^2-1}.$$

So the limit as $y\rightarrow 0$ of the function;
$$\frac{1}{y^2-1},$$
is just the value of the function when $y=0,$ which is;
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{y^2-1}
&=\frac{1}{0-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{-1}\\
&=-1.
\end{align*}

Therefore, bringing it together gives us the original limit;
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x(y^2 - 1)}
&=\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\right)\left(\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{(y^2 - 1)}\right)\\
&=\left(2\right)\left(-1\right)\\
&=-2.
\end{align*}
This is what you needed :)

[Note: I've not done this 'heavy' maths for a long time, and while I've taken the steps to ensure I've not made any mistakes.  Feels kinda like seeing a friend you've not seen in a long time...  nerve-
wracking.]

Comment: +1, great response, but I made some light edits to make it more clear and easier to understand.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that do not meet the [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) (see in particular "Spread the Word").

Comment: @Gary  My apologies.  In my excitement to find a question I can answer, I unknowingly violated the site rule.  This won't happen again.

Comment: @Gary. This seems a legit question to me. The answer deals with concepts I was not aware existed and it was a great source of knowledge. I have searched youtube for limit with multi variables and watched many classes in khan academy and could not find any one who would explain me what that answer could. I understand that must be a simple concept for someone who had the opportunity to receive a formal education, but for people who are struggling to learn by themselves these answers are very helpful. You should suggest edits before closing a questions.